# Where should i define BroadcastReceiver in Service or MainActivity

Tags: android, performance, service, android-service, android-broadcast

**If i define BroadcastReceiver in Service not in MainActivity, will it will consume more battery , because there are two process running for single app.. Or it will be fine.**

OR

**My app will consume same amount of battery and ram in a device.. Even after i am using BroadcastReceiver  and Service to perform a task happening in BroadcastReceiver.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs: "when a process executes a receiver (that is, currently running the code in its onReceive() method), it is considered to be a foreground process". For this reason, you should not start long running background threads from a broadcast receiver and I would prefer running it in the Activity.

Link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: So i should delete the service and only use BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Start your receiver in Activity unless you want to do something when the app is closed. But even so don`t forget to unregister your broadcastReceiver to avoid leaks when theres no need to have one.